# ConcurrentModificationException when trying initialize ArrayList's items with their listenners

Tags: kotlin, collections, concurrentmodification

I got `ConcurrentModificationException` when trying initialize a `ArrayList<CheckBox>` as blow:

```
     late init var checkBoxArrayList = ArrayList<CheckBox>()
     val repeatDays: List<Int> = getRepeatDays() // List of the order of days of the week starts from 1 (monday)
     
    
     checkBoxArrayList = arrayListOf(
        checkBoxMon.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)},
        checkBoxTue.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)},
        checkBoxWed.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)},
        checkBoxThu.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)},
        checkBoxFri.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)},
        checkBoxSat.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)},
        checkBoxSun.apply { this.isChecked = false
            this.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)}
    )
    repeatDays?.forEach { day ->
        // The checkBoxArrayList starts from index 0 (for monday), while the DayOfWeek enum assigns monday to 1.
        checkBoxArrayList[day - 1].isChecked = true

    }
```

But when I change the code as below, this issue is gone. I don't understand how the `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` impact and cause the error?. Could you give me an explanation.

```
    checkBoxArrayList = arrayListOf(
        checkBoxMon.apply { this.isChecked = false },
        checkBoxTue.apply { this.isChecked = false },
        checkBoxWed.apply { this.isChecked = false },
        checkBoxThu.apply { this.isChecked = false },
        checkBoxFri.apply { this.isChecked = false },
        checkBoxSat.apply { this.isChecked = false },
        checkBoxSun.apply { this.isChecked = false }
    )

    repeatDays?.forEach { day ->
        checkBoxArrayList[day - 1].isChecked = true

    }

    checkBoxArrayList.forEach {
        it.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)
    }
```

Comment: Hi. It seems to me that there's some code missing in your question. Definitions for `repeatDays` and `setOnCheckedChangeListener` seems to be required to solve the issue. BR

Comment: @RoarS. @RoarS. I add the declaration of `checkBoxArrayList` and `repeatDays`. `checkBoxArrayList` is a ArrayList of CheckBoxs and their checked states (true/false) are based on the value in `repeatDays`.  `ConcurrentModificationException` issue happened when I add `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for checkbox when initializing `checkBoxArrayList ` and I don't know why. In my understanding this issue usually happen when trying to modify element of Collection (such as remove()) during it's loop

Comment: rough guess but `setOnCheckedChangeListener(this@RepeatOptionsFragment)}` might access the arraylist while its being initialized

using the reference to a arryalist while its not fully assigned i'd expect to a be a different exception.. but evidence points to kotlin-stdlib building it and whatever the listeners do.. mess with it during that..